# What's left to do in Neverwinter Nights 2 official campaign?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I have been playing the NWN2 official campaign and been now at the estate part, and as far as I see I have upgraded every part of the estate, and don't know what to do further.

It's been a while since I played it last, so I might miss a few details.
Anyone out there to tell me what I should do next for a major move?
Training armies and walking around the grounds has become a bit boring now :)

Comment: Need a bit more information to go on here. Can you give us an idea of what you did last to advance the plot?

Comment: I spent some more time tonight, and found out I needed to talk to Kana again to get the battle started. Why that didn't strike me back then is a mystery to me :/

Comment: If only someone told me how to end this question gracefully, now that I already found an answer..

Comment: well, that's an option, but like I said, "gracefully" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking to Kana again did the trick.